# A Problem in Scaling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, units, scaling

> **Question: -** If the size of the nucleus (in the range of $10^{-15} m$ to $10^{-11} m $) is scaled up to the tip of a sharp pin, what roughly is the size of an atom? (Assume the tip of the pin to be in the range of $10^{-5}m$ to $10^{-4}m$.)
>
> **Answer: -** The size of a nucleus is in the range of $10^{-15} m$ and $10^{-11} m $. The tip of the sharp pin is taken to be in the range of $10^{-5}m$ to $10^{-4}m$. Thus we are scaling up by a factor of $1m$. An atom roughly of size $10^{-10}m$ will be scaled up to the size of $1m$. Thus a nucleus in an atom is as small in size as the tip of a sharp pin placed at the centre of a sphere of radius about a meter long.

Ok, now my attempt at understanding the problem went as far as the 'Thus we are scaling up by a factor of $1m$'.

*Question: -* Why did he have to scale it to $1m$, why not $1cm$ or $50cm$ or even $60cm$?

Edit: - I somewhat understood scaling but the above question remains a doubt

Comment: 1 m is not a scaling factor. Scaling factors are dimensionless.

Comment: Can you please send some links to tutorials on scaling? I haven't understood the mathematical aspect of it as to why we scale and such.

Comment: I don’t know of any such tutorials. Scaling just deals with ratios, so it isn’t complicated. For example, 1 cm is to 1 m as 1 km is to 100 km. Both ratios of distances are  1:100. The point of scaling in your example is to visualize an atom using distances that your eye can see… just “make it bigger” but in a way the maintains proportion between nucleus and atom.

Comment: [Here's a photograph of a textbook containing this question](https://static-images.findfilo.com/classroom/1624691341469_zbmdjiov_5752.jpg). It says $10^{10}$, not $1m$, and $10^{-14}$, not $10^{-11}$. I think the text you quoted is just bad automatic OCR of the textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easier-to-grasp example of scaling.

Start with an orange. its skin contains atoms, stuck together.

Now blow that orange up until it is the size of the earth. The atoms in its skin are being magnified too. When the orange is the size of the earth, the atoms in its skin are each about the size of an orange.